# Getting error "Error: Could not find or load main class A Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: A" in MAC OSX

Tags: java, macos, java-8

**MAC OSX**

I have the java source file A.java in "$HOME/Documents/personal_documents/java".

```
class A
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {

 }
}
```

Executed following commands:-

1. cd $HOME/Documents/personal_documents/java
2. javac A.java  **('Got successfully executed')**
3. java A **('Threw the error': Error: Could not find or load main class A
   , Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: A)**

Troubleshooting I did on my part:-

1. /usr/libexec/java_home

   **/Users/rishabshinghal/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14.0.1/Contents/Home**
2. Tried setting JAVA_HOME, PATH env variables explicitly.

   **export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14.0.1/Contents/Home/bin**

   **export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)**
3. Tried executing javac, java using absolute paths

   **$HOME/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14.0.1/Contents/Home/bin/javac A.java**

   **$HOME/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14.0.1/Contents/Home/bin/java A**
4. Also tried setting classpath explicitly even though I am in the same directory as class file.

   **javac A.java**

   **java -cp . A**

Please help me in this. I spent lot of time in troubleshooting this but didn't get any breakthrough.

Comment: Are you sure there is not package defined in A.java file?

Comment: No, there is no package defined inside A.java

Answer (score -2):

public static void main(String[]Args) try this, i hope it helps